# Comparing the value of a row in a certain column to the values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, indexing

Using Pandas

I'm trying to determine whether a value in a certain row is greater than the values in all the other columns in the same row.
To do this I'm looping through the rows of a dataframe and using the 'all' function to compare the values in other columns; but it seems this is throwing an error "string indices must be integers"

It seems like this should work: What's wrong with this approach?

```
for row in dataframe:
    if all (i < row['col1'] for i in [row['col2'], row['col3'], row['col4'], row['col5']]):
        row['newcol'] = 'value'
```

Comment: Iterating over a dataframe object is the same as iterating over its column headers. You probably want to check out the [`df.iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a mask and pass it to `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['col1'] > df.loc[:, 'col2':'col5'].max(axis=1), 'newcol'] = 'newvalue'
```

Comment: Very smart. Thank you very much

Comment: Is there a way to use this method with columns that aren't right after one another, for example df.loc[:, ('col1', 'col3':'col5')] ; or would this not work? Thank you

Comment: @SAtt it would not work unless you reordered your columns. Else, explicitly list out each column name in a list.

Comment: How did you get to the point where you can come up with this answer so quickly? thank you.

Comment: @SAtt You're welcome... I've been working with pandas for around 8 months... my profile shows I've answered more than my fair share of these kinds of questions ;), so I have an idea of common dev issues and pitfalls -- this lets me provide help more effectively to users such as yourself. I invite you to do the same, this is a wonderful community and you will learn a lot - certainly it will be worth your time. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem, in my opinion, is using a loop for vectorisable logic.

Below is an example of how your logic can be implemented using `numpy.where`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 9, (5, 10)))

df['new_col'] = np.where(df[1] > df.max(axis=1),
                         'col1_is_max',
                         'col1_not_max')
```

Result:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9       new_col
0  4  1  3  8  3  2  5  1  1  2  col1_not_max
1  2  7  1  2  5  3  5  1  8  5   col1_is_max
2  1  8  2  5  7  4  0  3  6  3   col1_is_max
3  6  4  2  1  7  2  0  8  3  2  col1_not_max
4  0  1  3  3  0  3  7  4  4  1  col1_not_max
```